# How can i make a node HTTP request that sends both file and data to a url?

Tags: node.js, http, node-modules

I need to make a HTTP request to an api with Node, but the api requires me to send both auth parameters and a file in the Request body. I tried using the node request, but the file wasn't sent.

```js
    let req= require('request').post({
        uri:"http://theAPIURL",
        headers:{'content-type': 'application/json'},
        form:{'username':'username','client_id':'client_id','user_pass':'user_pass#',
                'fisier':fs.createReadStream('../home/modules/file.csv')
            },

    }
```

Comment: "but the api requires me to send both auth parameters and a file in the Request body" — And what format does it expect them to be sent it (because it almost certainly isn't `application/json`!) (If you know the format then you can probably find the answer wtih Google).

Comment: **Danger** [the `request` module is deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and is now unsupported.